# Avoid floating-point precision error in algorithm

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-point-precision

In my 2D physics simulation (Java) I calculate the center of a convex polygon as follows, where the parameter *area* is the enclosed area of the polygon calculated before.

```java
private Vector2d calculateCenterOfMass(double area) {
    Vector2d center = new Vector2d(0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
        int j = (i + 1) % vertices.length;
        double factor = (vertices[i].x * vertices[j].y
                       - vertices[j].x * vertices[i].y);
        center.x += (vertices[i].x + vertices[j].x) * factor;
        center.y += (vertices[i].y + vertices[j].y) * factor;
    }
    center.scale(1 / (area * 6));

    return center;
}
```

I further have a polygon with the following points I use the function to calculate the center of mass of:

```
Vector2d [x=325.20399446366355, y=400.0, length=515.5168649182318]
Vector2d [x=375.20399446366355, y=400.0, length=548.4323453822622]
Vector2d [x=375.20399446366355, y=450.0, length=585.8993407245727]
Vector2d [x=325.20399446366355, y=450.0, length=555.2095442399406]
```

As you can see just by looking at the **y** values the center must be at **y=425.0**. Due to floating point magic the y value becomes **425.00000000000017** instead. The area given as parameter has the exact value **2500.0**.

**How can I avoid this and get my expected 425.0?**

Comment: Use `java.math.BigDecimal` instead of double

Comment: You should read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: If you don't need that much precision you can just round the number to, say, 2 decimal places...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BigDecimal` could help, but I would suggest reading the whole answer.

Floating point errors are 'normal' in a sense, that you cannot store every floating point number **exact** within a variable. There are many resources out there how to deal with this problem, a few links here:

1. If you do not know what the actual problem is check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0) out.
2. [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Poit Arithmetic](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf)
3. [IEEE floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)
4. To give you an idead how to work: [Quantity Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/quantity.html)

Comment: Your links really helped to understand the problem. So you will get the mark! I end up with a cast to float and back to double. That rounds my numbers in respect to the magnitude of the value with float precision. Do you have any idea how I can reach a higher precision (float < X < double) since float is still very inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

Use Double to calculate and Long to store.